# CrossRider - Show Local Database is not updated until I refresh the page

Tags: database, debugging, crossrider

Show Local Database is not updated until I refresh the page (in debug mode). Only after I refresh the page I can see the updated database.

The URL is http://crossrider.com/apps/43889/debug.

I'm using Internet Explorer 11.

Comment: Which browser are you debugging in?

Comment: I'm using Internet Explorer 11.

Comment: Thanks for reporting the issue. I have reproduced the issue and have asked the dev team to take a look, though it may take a while.